# How to remove local Microsoft Access links to the master copy

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I want to copy the Access database from my PROD server and save it in my local so that I can make some changes to it, test and then push it to PROD.  But when I copy the file from PROD server and save it in my local machine, even the changes that I make in local gets pushed and reflected in PROD copy.  I don't understand how that is possible but can someone suggest how I can un-link or save a local copy which would not cause such problems.

Comment: Is the database split? Access allows you to separate the tables from the forms/reports/queries into two separate files for networking. If you are copying the front-end, any changes you make will still get pushed into the back-end (if you're editing data).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your linked tables are in another Access db (the backend, or BE), you should also copy that one locally, then open the front-end (FE) and relink your linked tables so that they point to your local copy of the BE. You can do this by right clicking a linked table and select "Linked table manager".
And of course when you are ready to deploy, you have to do the opposite: relink to the "prod" FE.
I generally do that with a VBA proc that also changes the background color of the main form, so I have a visual clue of which environment I am currently impacting.